# Android app not connecting to socket server on LAN

Tags: android, lan

I have a PC running on my LAN which is listening on port 5001 and simply echos the text to the screen if a client connects and sends some data.

If I use the same code below on a simply java client program say running on a pc on the lan then I see on the server console that the client connected successfully.

Then I have an Android phone with the same client java code, see below initiated from clicking a button on the app but this doesn't seem to get to the server.

I have connected the Android phone to my LAN via a wifi connection.

Here is my button click code:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.20", 5001);
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
        output.println("Hello from Android");
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cubic.angus.buttonsend">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

I think the key thing is to have this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Although I am connecting on a LAN, maybe INTERNET is not the correct option.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have some webserver on the same pc? Can you reach it from the android with any browser? Does internet work on the phone as it should?

Comment: It may help to log the exception on the line that says `// do nothing`

Comment: try something like ping your server from phone. Makesure that it is accessible from the phone.